# Procedure to rename a list of procedure, only renames the last procedure in the list

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I created a procedure where I could pass a list of procedure names separated by a comma, and then I would like to rename all the procedures from the list by adding a custom suffix in the end.

But I am facing an issue where it would only rename the last item from the list and ignore all the rest. I don't know why it would not rename each one from table variable list since I am calling `sp_rename` on each item in the list.

Also, I was able to print each loop with `raiseerror()`

Here's the complete procedure that I written.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Util_ProcRename]
    @ProcNameListWithComma VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ID INT
    SET @ID = 1;

    DECLARE @oldname varchar(200)
    DECLARE @newname varchar(200);

    DECLARE @NOTUSED VARCHAR(20)
    SET @NOTUSED = '_NOTUSED_'+REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(20), GETDATE(), 101),'/','')

    DECLARE @ProList AS TABLE (
                           ID INT IDENTITY,
                           ProcName VARCHAR(200),
                           NewProcName VARCHAR(200)
                          );

    --Get proc names from a list into a table with ID to use in While loop
    INSERT INTO @ProList (ProcName)
        SELECT P AS ProcName
        FROM dbo.SplitText(@ProcNameListWithComma,',')

    WHILE (@id <= (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @ProList)) 
    BEGIN  
        SET @oldname = (SELECT ProcName FROM @ProList WHERE ID = @ID)
        SET @newname = @oldname + @NOTUSED

        EXEC p_rename @oldname, @newname

        SET @ID = @ID + 1
    END

    UPDATE p
    SET NewProcName = p.ProcName+@NOTUSED
    FROM @ProList p
    WHERE ID = ID

    --TO see the list that got renamed 
    SELECT 
        a.Name AS [NewName], 
        a.type
    FROM  
        dbo.sysobjects a
    WHERE 
        name IN (SELECT NewProcName FROM @ProList)
END
GO
```

Comment: You could solve this by checking all of your stored procedures into your source control system and then just deleting the ones you don't use from the server.

Comment: My company doesn't want to delete anything, that's why I need to rename with prefix _NOTUSED_<DATE>

Comment: In source control == not deleted.

Comment: @EricBrandt Yup I miss understood.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the indentation, you are doing the `update` *after* the loop.  So, it is only called once.

Move the `END` to after the `UPDATE`.

Comment: I thought this too, but (at least in the question), it is `WHERE ID = ID` so the whole table should be updated in one call.  I wonder if it isn't `WHERE ID = @ID` in the actual code.

Comment: I want it after the loop, So having it WHERE ID = ID, would update the whole list in the table variable and then I pull information from sysobjects to visually compare the list that I  passed in my call to proc and what got return.
The problem is that when I did raiseerror I got the whole list printed out, but when I ran with the EXEC sp_rename it only renamed the last one from the list.